# Plot with colors depending on data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-python

I would like to plot some data but with colors depending on certain conditions. Ideally I would like to do it in both plotly and matplotlib (separate scripts)

**The data**

For example I have the following data

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'Y': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1,2,3,4,5,5],
    'XL': [2,    None, 4,    None, None,None,4,5,None,3],
    'YL': [3,    None, 2,    None, None,None,5,6,None,4],
    'XR': [None, 4,    None, 1,    None,None,None,4,5,4],
    'YR': [None, 3,    None, 5,    None,None,None,3,4,4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**The simple plots**

So with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot X, Y
ax.plot(df['X'], df['Y'], linestyle='-', marker='o')

# Update plot settings
ax.set_title('Trajectory Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

and with plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create a scatter plot
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df['X'], y=df['Y'], mode='lines+markers'))

# Update layout for better visibility
fig.update_layout(
    title='Trajectory Plot',
    xaxis_title='X-axis',
    yaxis_title='Y-axis',
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

**The problem**

I would like to modify the scripts so that I can use a different color depending on the existence or not of the `(XL,YL)` and `(XR,YR)` pairs.

- Grey: none exist
- Red: Only XL,YL exists
- Blue: Only XR,YR exists
- Green: Both exists

In the end it should be like this (pardon the crude picture, I painted over the original blue lines)

How can I add this in matplotlib and plotly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use matplotlib's [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection), see example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html)

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap

# COLOR map
arr = np.array(['green']*len(df), dtype=str) # both exist # default
arr[df['XL'].isna() & df['XR'].isna()] = 'grey' # none exist
arr[~df['XL'].isna() & df['XR'].isna()] = 'red' # only L
arr[df['XL'].isna() & ~df['XR'].isna()] = 'blue' # only R

# generate line-segments
points = np.array([df['X'], df['Y']]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=arr)

lc.set_linewidth(2)
line = ax.add_collection(lc)

# add a scatter for point markers
ax.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], c=arr)

ax.set_xlim(df['X'].min()-1, df['X'].max()+1)
ax.set_ylim(df['Y'].min()-.1, df['Y'].max()+.1)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

For plotly the best solution you can have is:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import itertools as it

# create coordinate  pairs
x_pairs = it.pairwise(df['X'])
y_pairs = it.pairwise(df['Y'])

# create base figure
fig = go.Figure()

# add traces (line segments)
for x, y, color in zip(x_pairs, y_pairs, arr):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=y, 
            mode='lines+markers', 
            line={'color': color}
        )
    )
    
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can also add (for matplotlib) `zorder=2` to make sure that the points appear above the lines just as a cosmetic difference (`ax.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], c=arr,zorder=2)`

Comment: I marked this as correct answer. There is a problem thought. All of the segments are cataloged as a different trace... this presents a problem. There should be only four labels (only left, only right, both and none)

Comment: I didn't understand, what do you mean exactly? Is it that when you try adding labels you get duplicates? and for which graph `plt` or `plotly`?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to just plot the whole dataset first, without markers. Then, on top of that, plot the markers coloured according to the conditions that you mentioned.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {
    'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'Y': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1,2,3,4,5,5],
    'XL': [2,    None, 4,    None, None,None,4,5,None,3],
    'YL': [3,    None, 2,    None, None,None,5,6,None,4],
    'XR': [None, 4,    None, 1,    None,None,None,4,5,4],
    'YR': [None, 3,    None, 5,    None,None,None,3,4,4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grey_cond = (df['XL'].isnull() | df['YL'].isnull()) & (df['XR'].isnull() | df['YR'].isnull())
red_cond = (df['XL'].notnull() & df['YL'].notnull()) & (df['XR'].isnull() | df['YR'].isnull())
blue_cond = (df['XR'].notnull() & df['YR'].notnull()) & (df['XL'].isnull() | df['YL'].isnull())
green_cond = df['XR'].notnull() & df['YR'].notnull() & df['XL'].notnull() & df['YL'].notnull()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot X, Y
ax.plot(df['X'], df['Y'], linestyle='-', color='black')
# Grey condition (none exist)
ax.plot(df['X'][grey_cond], df['Y'][grey_cond],
    color='None',
    marker='o',
    markeredgecolor='grey',
    markerfacecolor='grey'
)
# Red condition (only XL, YL exist)
ax.plot(df['X'][red_cond], df['Y'][red_cond],
    color='None',
    marker='o',
    markeredgecolor='red',
    markerfacecolor='red'
)
# Blue condition (only XR, YR exist)
ax.plot(df['X'][blue_cond], df['Y'][blue_cond],
    color='None',
    marker='o',
    markeredgecolor='blue',
    markerfacecolor='blue'
)
# Green condition (Both exist)
ax.plot(df['X'][green_cond], df['Y'][green_cond],
    color='None',
    marker='o',
    markeredgecolor='green',
    markerfacecolor='green'
)

# Update plot settings
ax.set_title('Trajectory Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The output will look like this:
[image: output picture]

This does not have the coloured lines too, but I think it should be more correct this way.
Otherwise, you would have to choose which side (left or right) to your markers (data points) you want to plot of the same colour of the marker.

You can also add a legend if you want, by adding `label` to each marker plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot X, Y
ax.plot(df['X'], df['Y'], linestyle='-', color='black',label="Trajectory")
# Grey condition (none exist)
ax.plot(df['X'][grey_cond], df['Y'][grey_cond],
    color='None',
    marker='o',
    markeredgecolor='grey',
    markerfacecolor='grey',
    label='Neither XL,YL nor XR,YR exist'
)
# Red condition (only XL, YL exist)
ax.plot(df['X'][red_cond], df['Y'][red_cond],
    color='None',
    marker='o',
    markeredgecolor='red',
    markerfacecolor='red',
    label='Only XL,YL exist'
)
# Blue condition (only XR, YR exist)
ax.plot(df['X'][blue_cond], df['Y'][blue_cond],
    color='None',
    marker='o',
    markeredgecolor='blue',
    markerfacecolor='blue',
    label='Only XR,YR exist'
)
# Green condition (Both exist)
ax.plot(df['X'][green_cond], df['Y'][green_cond],
    color='None',
    marker='o',
    markeredgecolor='green',
    markerfacecolor='green',
    label='Both XL,YL and XR,YR exist'
)

# Update plot settings
ax.set_title('Trajectory Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output with the legend will look like this:
[image: output figure with legend]

Hope this makes sense

Cheers
Davide